# How to extract and store in a variable only the month and year (as string) from a date that comes from server in this format dd/mm/yyyy?

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex, angular

I'm working on an Angular project, and I'm consuming a service that brings me an array of objects.

Each object has this structure:

```
{   loc_snombre: "Flying peaches "
    ncr_dfhoemision: "24-09-2019"
    ncr_nidnotacredito: 1900015060
}
```

I need to be able to get the value from the property `ncr_dfhoemision` and store it in a variable, but only extracting the year and the month (as a string, all together), so the variable, in this case, would be:

```
var monthAndYear = "201909"
```

I think I could maybe use regex, but, I'm not being able to accomplish it. ¿How could I accomplish this? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use destructuring with `String.split()`, and then combine the values with a template literal:

```js
const obj = {
  loc_snombre: "Flying peaches ",
  ncr_dfhoemision: "24-09-2019",
  ncr_nidnotacredito: 1900015060
}

const [, month, year] = obj.ncr_dfhoemision.split('-')

const result = `${year}${month}`

console.log(result)
```

Another option is to split by `-`, slice out the 1st item (the day), reverse, and join:

```js
const obj = {
  loc_snombre: "Flying peaches ",
  ncr_dfhoemision: "24-09-2019",
  ncr_nidnotacredito: 1900015060
}

const result = obj.ncr_dfhoemision
  .split('-')
  .slice(1)
  .reverse()
  .join('')

console.log(result)
```